# Make Batch File Display Random Text?

Tags: text, random, batch-file, line

I would like to make a batch file that uses an external .txt file filled with custom slogans in the same directory, and in the batch file, they enter a word, and it will insert it into the slogan using set /p. Here is what the .txt file might look like:

Pure %name%.
Truly %name&.
%name% - good to know.
Powered by %name%.

Then the batch file will read the .txt file and display the line with what the user entered earlier. So, how would I do this? Also, it has to randomize what it displays every time. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, I probably should take this down, but I found the answer, I'll post the finished script in the question or something, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@set @e=0 /*
  @echo off
    set @e=
    set /p "name=Enter a name: "
    cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" %name%
  exit /b
*/

var rnd = rnd || {
  getRandomNumber : function(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  },

  printSloganString : function(str) {
     var slogans = {
        0 : 'Pure ' + str,
        1 : 'Truly ' + str,
        2 : str + ' - good to know',
        3 : 'Powered by ' + str
     };

     return slogans[this.getRandomNumber(0, 3)];
  }
}

with (WScript.Arguments) {
   try {
      var itm = Unnamed(0);
      WScript.echo(rnd.printSloganString(itm));
   }
   catch (e) {
      WScript.echo(e.message);
   }
}
```

Save it like batch (.CMD or .BAT) and invoke.